# Can't insert new records through PHP into mysql database

Tags: php, mysql

When I press the submit button I get error.

> object not found error.

And the page automatically adds empty entries with auto incremented primary key (without pressing the submit button).

I am still a beginner in PHP, I searched thoroughly but I can't find out what's wrong in code.

```
  <html>   
<head>
    <title>Add New Record in MySQL Database</title>
</head>   
<body>
    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
        <p>

            <label for="Name">Full Name:</label>

            <input type="text" name="Name" id="Name">

        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="Code">Code:</label>
            <input type="text" name="Code" id="Code">
        </p>
        <p>
            <label for="GPA">GPA:</label>
            <input type="text" name="GPA" id="GPA">
        </p>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php
 /* Attempt MySQL server connection. Assuming you are running MySQL

 server with default setting (user 'root' with no password) */

 $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "students");
// Check connection

if ($link === false) {

die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// Escape user inputs for security
$full_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'full_name');
$code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'code');
$gpa = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gpa');
// attempt insert query execution
$sql = "INSERT INTO info VALUES ('$full_name', '$code', '$gpa')";
if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
 echo "Records added successfully. $full_name";
} else {
 echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
}
// close connection
mysqli_close($link);
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You need to check wither or not the form has been processed. I prefer to have the processing of the form in a separate php-file than the actual form.

Comment: You are open to SQL injections.

Comment: What should I do about the SQL injections?

Comment: You should escape them [mysqli_escape](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Comment: please don't update your code with the answers given. Now the answers don't make sense with the question, so I rollback your edits

Comment: Don't escape your inputs. Use prepared statements and bind your inputs separately.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
$full_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Name');
$code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'Code');
$gpa = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'GPA');
```

The reason why I wrote that is because your input names contain `Name`, `Code` and `GPA` so you need to write this exactly as your input names (**case-sensitive**).

Comment: I can give you multiple steps on how to find an error and print it but it's better to move from comments (to email? chat?) since this will not fit in here. If through email, you can find it in my profile, if through chat, just create it but then you'll have to notify me each time since for some reasons I don't get notifications.

Comment: It works now, had to move the php code to another file separate from the form and add \" to string variables in the query.

Answer (score 6):

Do with `isset()`. when the submit button clicks only the code runs.

Inside the php you should use the form input name field.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $link = mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "students");
    if ($link === false) {
        die("ERROR: Could not connect. " . mysqli_connect_error());
    }
    // Escape user inputs for security
    $full_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'full_name');
    $code = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'code');
    $gpa = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'gpa');

    //to prevent sql injection attack
    $full_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $full_name);
    $code = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $code);
    $gpa  = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $gpa);

    // attempt insert query execution
    $sql = "INSERT INTO info (Name,Code,GPA) VALUES ('$full_name', '$code', '$gpa')";
    if (mysqli_query($link, $sql)) {
        echo "Records added successfully. $full_name";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($link);
    }
    // close connection
     mysqli_close($link);
}
?>
<html>   
<head>
  <title>Add New Record in MySQL Database</title>
</head>   
<body>
    <form action="insert.php" method="post">
    <p>
        <label for="Name">Full Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="full_name" id="Name">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="Code">Code:</label>
        <input type="text" name="code" id="Code">
    </p>
    <p>
        <label for="GPA">GPA:</label>
        <input type="text" name="gpa" id="GPA">
    </p>
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: please mention the table structure of `info`.

Comment: info is a table in "students" db, it has 3 columns;Name, Code, GPA and 2 rows of data.

Comment: where is Auto increment Column as you mentioned in the question.? i edited the Answer.

Comment: Please Check it now. It Will Works. @TasneemSalah

Answer (score 2):

The problem is the input name. You named Full Name input with `name="Name"`, but you declare `$full_name = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'full_name');` in php section. you must change `full_name` to `Name`. As well as the Code and GPA input.

Comment: @EdvinTenovimas ahh, you're right. i'm sorry i dont pay attention.. i just vote up your answer :)

Comment: Well, thanks! :) It's ok if you didn't notice, that happens to everyone.